# What is network byte order?

Tags: endianness

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-example.html
Example 34.3. libpq Example Program 3

```
/* Convert integer value "2" to network byte order */
binaryIntVal = htonl((uint32_t) 2);
printf("binaryIntVal:%d\n",binaryIntVal);
```

it will get the expected tuple,also return `binaryIntVal:33554432`

---

if I instead use `binaryIntVal    = (uint32_t) 2;`
then it will not get the expected tuple (the executed query will be `SELECT * from test1 where i = NULL`
it also return `binaryIntVal:2`

server and client is in the same machine. I use socket for connection.
I found related post in here: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=hosts-network-byte-order

So what's network byte order, why here need to use it?

Comment: [Network byte order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Networking) is nothing specific to Postgres.

Comment: "*server and client is in the same machine*" - doesn't matter. The endianness of integers in the protocol is the same regardless whether you are connecting from/to a remote machine or not - making it dependent on the destination would be crazy and complicated to implement.